# Avoid duplicate data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a csv file from stock that is updated every day.
I want to enter this data in a table and Just add new data every day.
this is my code:

```
# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
import csv
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host= 'localhost',
                              user= 'root',
                              passwd='pass',
                              db='stock')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
               name VARCHAR(50), day DATE UNIQUE, open float, high float, low float,
               close float, vol float, PRIMARY KEY(id))""")
a = 0
with open("file path")as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        if a== 0 :
            a=+1
        else:
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO stock(name,day,open,high,low,close,vol)
            VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")''',
            (row[0],int(row[1]),float(row[2]),float(row[3]),float(row[4]),
            float(row[5]),float(row[6])))
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

But I can not prevent duplication of information

Comment: You could define a unique constraint in the table schema, which would cause the `INSERT` of a duplicate to fail.  Your code should handle that error, of course.  Or you could check for the existance of a record before inserting it.  Or perhaps remove duplicates from the in-memory data before inserting it.  What logic are you trying to implement and what attempt are you making?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to avoid duplicates on `(name, day)`, one approach would be to set a unique key on this tuple of columns. You can then use `insert ignore`, or better yet `on duplicate key` syntax to skip the duplicate rows.

You create the table like:

```
create table if not exists stock(
    id int auto_increment ,
    name varchar(50), 
    day date, 
    open float, 
    high float, 
    low float,
    close float, 
    vol float, 
    primary key(id),
    unique (name, day) -- unique constraint
);
```

Then:

```
insert into stock(name,day,open,high,low,close,vol)
values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
on duplicate key update name = values(name)  -- dummy update
```

Notes:

- you should not have double quotes around the `%s` placeholders
- your original `create table` code had a unique constraint on column `day`; this does not fit with your question, as I understood it. In any case, you should put the `unique` constraint on the column (or set of columns) on which you want to avoid duplicates.